# Simple inequality proof?

Tags: inequality

How do I show this inequality:

For positive real numbers $a,b$ such that $a+b=1$ then $\frac{2}{\frac{a}{x}+ \frac{b}{y}} \leq ax + by$ for $x, y > 0$

Comment: Are you sure the LHS has numerator $2$ and not $1$? Your inequality does not hold for say $a=b=x=y=\frac12$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $2$ in your inequality should be $1$. Indeed,

$$(ax + by)\left(\frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{y}\right) = a^2 + b^2 + ab\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right) \ge a^2 + b^2 + 2ab\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}\frac{y}{x}} = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab = (a + b)^2  = 1,$$

with equality if and only if $x = y$.

Comment: You can apply the Cauchy-Schawarz Inequality right away, but anyway nice proof.

Comment: @Stefan4024 yes I know that, but I figured this way might be easier to follow.